# The Height of a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis

thank you in advance.  so I am reading about the algebraic numbers and have a question about the definition "height" ..  the book isn't clear.

so given 
$$p(x)=a_0 + a_{1}x+...+a_{n}x^{n} = 0$$
where $x$ is an algebraic number if this is satisfied.  Attached to each polynomial $p$ is the "height" defined as $$h = n + a_n + |a_{n-1}| + ... +|a_{0}|$$

where each of these $a_{i}$ is the coordinate/coefficient of $p(x)$.  Now, for each $(a_0,....,a_n)$ there is a unique $p(x)$ with degree $n$, with at most $n$ solutions, and there are infinitely many of these $p(x)$.

Here is my question..... the book says for $h=3$ we have the polynomials  $\{3, x-1,x+1,2x,x^{2} \}$

for $h =1$ admits no algebraic numbers.

for $h =2$  yields $2$, and $x$.

how does one calculate the height, and what does it mean with $p(x)$ ?

Comment: "hight"? Do you mean "height"? I never heard of polynomials having heights, but I never heard of the word hight in general, so...

Comment: this is from david sprecher pg 30  it says hight...dont know if its a typo...its an old text

Comment: The question is unclear in general. Can you provide a reference where the hight is defined? Also, why are you asking how to calculate the hight, isn't it straightforward by simply using the formula $n+a_n+...$?

Comment: the hight is defined exactly by the equation given called h. "attached to each polynomial p(x) is the number h called  hight...given by the forumla above.  i can not reproduce the sets the text has listed.

Comment: for h =3  where is x-1 and x+1 coming from? why is there not x^3 listed?

Comment: The way you wrote the definition, the "hight" (please, provide the title of the book where this is defined) of $x^3$ is $n+a_3+|a_2|+|a_1|+|a_0| = 3 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 4$, so the hight is not $3$ but $4$.

Comment: elements of real analysis , david a. sprecher, pg 30

Comment: This looks like part of a proof that the algebraic numbers are countable.

Comment: yes i have the proof for complex numbers

Comment: @5xum,  how did you calculate the scalar values for a2,a1,and a0?

Comment: @AnthonyColombo For $p(x)=x^3$, you know that $p(x)=x^3+0\cdot x^2+0\cdot x^1+0\cdot x^0$ so you can simply read $a_0=a_1=a_2=0$ off the polynomial.

Comment: thank you.  I edited out the mis-spellings and my question is answered. thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never heard of "hight" either.  I've heard of the "height" of an algebraic number, e.g. see [The Springer Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Algebraic_number).  This is somewhat different from your definition, but I think there are several different "height" functions in use.  This particular function is chosen so that there will be only finitely many algebraic numbers of a given "hight".

To calculate the "hight" of an algebraic number $\alpha$, you first need its minimal polynomial: a primitive (i.e. gcd of its coefficients is $1$) polynomial $p(x)$ with integer coefficients, having lowest possible degree, such that 
$p(\alpha) = 0$ and the highest coefficient is positive.  Then the "hight" is the degree plus the sum of the absolute values of the coefficients.

For example, for $\alpha = \sqrt{2}$ the minimal polynomial is $p(x) = x^2 - 2$.  The degree is $2$, the coefficients are $1,0,-2$, so the hight is $2 + 1 + 0 + 2 = 5$.

Comment: so the purpose of h is to have an upper bound on the degree, also we know there are finitely many equations which satisfy this value h.

Comment: It's puzzling why the book listed $p(x) = 3$ among the polynomials for $h=3.$ It seems it should not, for the same reason that there are no polynomials for $h=1.$